# Are there nuanced differences between the following expressions?

Tags: meaning, word-choice, word-usage, meaning-in-context, verbs

"**Close** the door."
"**Latch** the door."

I realize both verbs are synonymous and can be used interchangeably, but I'm struggling to explain and emphasize the minor difference.

Edit: My apologies for miswording the question, what I'm looking for is the difference in "emotional ties" aka "feeling evoked" when utilizing the above phrases.

SECOND EDIT (I'M A MESS): Let me present this excerpt from *Church Going* for those questioning the "emotional ties" part;

"Once I am sure there's nothing going on I step inside, *letting the door **thud** shut.*"

A thud can be interpreted by a muffled noise as a weighted object strikes a solid surface. Since it’s not a sharp sound, thud evokes the feeling of confidentiality.

My question is, how does *closing* the door versus *latching* the door change the connotation?

Comment: You can close a door without latching it. And you can latch a door before closing it (some types of latch). And you can latch a door that is already closed. And "latch" can mean the opposite with "latch the door" meaning "put it on the latch so it can be opened from outside."

Comment: I don't understand "What feeling is evoked..."// (after edit)...don't get "emotional ties" either.

Comment: 'Close the door' is hypernymous, and can mean anything from 'push it to (it'll stay in place, but the lock's fallen off') to 'Triple-lock and bolt it'. 'Latch the door' means 'fasten it in place with the latch' (with the strong suggestion that you're not to lock it properly).

Comment: You seem to want an emotional answer, so **latching** a door gives a reassuringly onomatopoeic feeling of security, whereas **closing** a door implies, to me, that some future path has been blocked, without knowing which...

Comment: The so-called 'emotional ties' i.e. "thud shut" come from context. These words do not have any emotional content apart from what the author gives them.

Comment: @WeatherVane Thank you so much, that was exactly what I was looking for.

Comment: My edit really prevented the 'emotional significance' that might reqasonably commonly be associated with the two different terms. But you're really asking for an answer that goes beyond the scope of nuts-and-bolts 'Language' here, and I'm sure that this would be a better fit on Lit.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the very subtle evocations (fringe connotations) of these two words are really better asked about on Literature.SE.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of connotation, "latch" conveys intentionality. A door can shut passively but to latch generally requires action from an outside force. For this reason, there's perhaps more permanence implied as well.

With respect to "shut", there is less implicitly communicated. You can shut a door in anger or the door can shut with a thud. The "shut" itself only has emotional weight with respect to the words around it.

> The door shut behind her with a thud. She latched it quietly and walked upstairs.

Comment: Welcome to English Language and Usage. Please take the [tour] and when you have a moment, read-up in the [help] about how we work. Good first answer.

Answer (score -2):

They're not synonomous. They cannot be used interchangeably.

Latched doors are always closed, but closed doors are not always latched. We can close doors without latching them—and usually do.

Comment: Please consider including citation, source, and possibly a link to support your supposition. Without support, this is only an opinion. We don't do opinions here.

Comment: Hotel doors have latches that allow you to crack the door while the latch is still engaged so you can see and talk through the crack while maintaining a physical barrier. Those doors are *latched* but **not** *closed*. So in addition to what @rattler said, your answer is incorrect (which is *why* we insist on citations). Please up your game wrt answers.